# mobile simple application, drag and drop

Tags: android, mobile, drag-and-drop

i didn't want to ask a question, but i don't have any solution at all.

i've not seen such a kind of problem. i decided to write applications on mobile platforms (android and iOS), but nothing found.

1. lots of tutorials and documentations
2. lots of samples
3. lots of libraries and frameworks

but nothing found... i'm fed up, still looking for difference between mobile web application and desktop. i wanted to write simple drag and drop calculator, searched and found phonegap + jQM. first, i installed eclipse + ADT + cordova and created project. when i started writing, i decided to use jQuery (cause i needed drag and drop effects), and suddenly found that i needed applaud plugin and so on... as i understand applaud app and native phonegap app are differenet. when i searhed, i found that phonegap + jQM are web apps and needed NET to start application. I don't want to write web app, i only want 3 - 4 line to undestand what' going on... what is difference between web and client app in mobile and how i can write simple drag and drop calculator NOT WEB. i'm really fed up with these tutorials and documentations, i only need correct starting way and then i will do myself. damn, i'm tired...

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, that's not how we roll: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A web app is an HTML5, JavaScript, CSS app running in a mobile browser typically published on a web server but can be run locally on a device without a network connection in some cases.

A native app is downloaded and installed on the mobile device and must be published to an external app store of some sort. There are also hybrid apps that combine both characteristics.

Native and hybrid apps have more complete access to the device platform and can be more performant than web apps but require more specialized language skill (Objective C, Java, C#).

Web apps can be as simple as a web site displayed on a mobile device and require much more broadly utilized skills such as HTML, JavaScript, and CSS.

The requirements of your drag and drop calculator are not specified but I would suggest that a very simple web app could meet your needs.

This IBM article might be overkill for you but it also happens to discuss the offline web app option. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-offlineweb/index.html